# Blazor custom component

Tags: components

I want to build a custom component where i have the option to "leave out" part of the code.
Say i have this simpleCard component:

```
 <div class="simpleCard">
        <div class="img-fluid">
            <img src="@imageUrl">
        </div>
        <div class="simpleCard-title">
            <p>@cardTitle</p>
        </div>
        <div class="simpleCard-text">
            <p>@cardText</p>
        </div>
         <button> class="simpleCard-button">Click me</button>
        </div>
    </div>


`@code `{
    [Parameter]
    public string imageUrl { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public string cardTitle { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public string cardText { get; set; }
}
```

When this simplecard component is called, is there a way to "ignore" the button class? Say i want to create one card with button and one without?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a parameter in your component for a boolean value:

```cs
[Parameter]
public bool ButtonVisible { get; set; }
```

Then in your markup:

```cs
@if(ButtonVisible)
{
 </div>
   <button> class="simpleCard-button">Click me</button>
 </div>
}
```

And when you call the component, set the value to true or false as needed:

```cs
.....

<Component ButtonVisible="True" .... />

...
```

The button will only render if you have the value set to True.

Comment: Thank you kind sir